# implement continuous delivery using puppet

Tags: puppet

We have a setup something like this:
a puppet master on linux and windows 2k8 server agents.
The build system compiles the code (visual studio), and creates a nuget package and uploads the same to nuget repository identified with a version number. To implement Continuos Delivery, we are using puppet and would like have a mechanism in which the new package created should be automatically deployed to the destination server. So whenever the sync of client happens with master, it checks what new version is available on puppet master and if there is a new version deploy it to the client. The deployment script is present but the problem that i am facing is how to get the version number to the puppet master after every build happens and how to compare it with the deployed version on the client.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are using for version control but we are utilizing github. We have puppet repos that store puppet manifests and then we have our software repo that the coders dev the product in. We use this tool to populate the /etc/puppet/environments with the puppet repos from github: https://github.com/adrienthebo/r10k

In the puppet manifests that are coming down they are broken up into projects e.g. /etc/puppet/$proj_qa /etc/puppet/$proj_dev etc. We have custom modules setup in puppet that pull code out of our software github onto each server based on commit. The devs when coding update the commit code in the puppet repo. Then R10k updates the puppet server based on the updated puppet git repo. I have r10k currently running every 5min or so in the crontab on our puppet server.

each puppet repo has seprate branches so the $proj will have dev, qa, prod etc then what r10k does is it can set them up so that they will appear as separate puppet environments e.g. /etc/environment/goodproject_dev, /etc/environment/goodproject_qa, /etc/environment/goodproject_prod based on the branches.

So you have dev - > merges to Qa. Qa tests everything then it can be merged to stage prod etc.

It took months to setup our puppet environment and continuos integration so not something that really can be fully answered in a stackoverflow post but I hope that you find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you are trying to deploy a package to an application server.   I'm assuming you have the version number in a metadata file that has been deployed with the package. Create two puppet custom [fact](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/custom_facts.html) which reference the version numbers on the client and master. Include these facts in your module.  Have your deployment compare them on your run, and deploy your package if the installed module version fact is less than your server facts.

Comment: update link to custom fact https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6/custom_facts.html